# Is 117 something like a magic number?

Tags: advice

Why is it that if you add the last 2 digits of your birth year + your age or the age you will become on any particular year it always adds up to 117? 
For example, I was born in 1975 and turned 42 this year so: 75+42=117
My dad was born on 1947 and turned 70 this year, so: 47+70=117.
My brother was born on 1985 and turned 32 this year: 85+32=117
Why is it always 117 for anyone born in the 1900's?

Comment: because this is the year of 2017? I bet the number will be 118 next year.

Comment: because birth year + age = current year, which is 2017.

Comment: That is because 1900+117=2017..

Comment: "In any particular year" is wrong. It's only true if you give you start with you age on Dec. 31, 2017 *and* you were born before 2000.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is now $2017$, which is $1900+117$.  If you were born in year $y$ of the $1900$s the last two digits of your birth year is $y-1900$ and your age now is $2017-y$.  Adding these gives $117$

Comment: So next year the magic number will be $118$.

Answer (score 3):

The definition of age (as long as you've had your birthday this year) is
$$
\text{Age} = \text{Current year} - \text{Birth year}
$$
Rearranging, we get
$$
\text{Age} + \text{Birth year} = \text{Current year}
$$
which is what you have observed. You're off by $1900$ (i.e. get $117$ instead of $2017$) because you're using only the last two digits of your birth year, which for people born in the twentieth century in practice means that you've subtracted $1900$ from the left-hand side of the last equation.

Comment: In particular, it doesn't work for anybody born in 2000 or later - then the result you get is $17$.